# Is it possible that google cloud bigquery has bad configured the order by statement?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to do an order by but Im receiving the error:

> SELECT list expression references column bierai_num_rut which is
> neither grouped nor aggregated at [3:12]

My query in Google Cloud Platform Bigquery is the next:

```sql
SELECT 
  periodo_esp, 
  case when bierai_num_rut < 50000000 then 1 else 0 end as persona_natural, 
  count(distinct bierai_num_rut) as rut_unicos, 
  count(bierai_num_rut) as n_rut, 
  sum(bierai_mon_avaluo_fiscal) as sum_avaluo_fiscal, 
  avg(bierai_mon_avaluo_fiscal) as avg_avaluo_fiscal, 
  stddev(bierai_mon_avaluo_fiscal) as stdev_avaluo_fiscal, 
  sum(bierai_mon_avaluo_exento_prop) as sum_avaluo_exento_prop, 
  avg(bierai_mon_avaluo_exento_prop) as avg_avaluo_exento_prop, 
  stddev(bierai_mon_avaluo_exento_prop) as stdev_avaluo_exento_prop 
FROM 
  `bch-prj-bdta-datalake-pro-cec1.production_universal_cyp.sat_bien_raiz_esp` 
group by 
  periodo_esp, 
  case when bierai_num_rut < 50000000 then 1 else 0 end 
order by 
  periodo_esp desc
```

What can I do? Why this SQL structure is running ok on a SQL server with the same info but in GCP is not working??

I just wanna have a table ordered by column `periodo_esp`.

Answer (score 1):

In your second `group by` column just replace it with `persona_natural` then it should work.